# How to use Google Checkout with Google AppEngine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-checkout

I have an AppEngine app. I'd like to add a payment system to it, and Google Checkout would seem the natural choice.

This should be simple, right? Google should want us to use their checkout, and provide handy jars and sample code. But after half an hour of web searching, the closest thing I found was how to use PayPal with appengine.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or other documentation?

Or is PayPal the better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-java-sdk/ which looks like is should work with GAE. The documentation is pretty poor and they don't seem to have many examples. From a quick glance at the source code everything seems to center around the com.google.checkout.sdk.commands.ApiContext class. You simply create a new instance and then you can pass in EnvironmentInterface.CommandType and the data model you like to the postCommand method. For example you would pass a EnvironmentInterface.CommandType.CART_POST and a com.google.checkout.sdk.domain.ShoppingCart instance for new orders.

Comment: Google links to some (official?) sample code at http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samplecode.html but, oddly, doesn't include Python.